# Label Text Not Showing Outside of Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Grid and on top of the grid, I like am showing a label as such:

```
    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
```

On delete of a row in my grid I have the following code:

```
    protected void RadGrid1_DeleteCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (!(User.IsInRole("Administrator")))
        {
           lblMsg.Text = "Must be an Admin in delete.";
           return;
        }
```

NOTE: The debugger does go to where I have the label text displayed but it simply does not display on the page. :

```
     lblMsg.Text = "Must be an Admin in delete.";
```

NOTE: If I have the same code in the page load, the label text shows up fine on the page Also DO NOT have (!IsPostBack){} in my code.

Comment: what does the debugger say? Place a breakpoint to see if it goes into that method

Comment: The debugger goes to where I have the code.

Comment: Is anything else assigning ` lblMsg.Text`?

Comment: Share `RadGrid1` code so that we can see if there is some error in the Grid itself.

Comment: Do you have if(!IsPostBack){} surrounding your page load? It could be that when the RadGrid1_DeleteCommand is being called and the page is posting back that the controls are being set back to their default value in Page_Load

Comment: I am not using if(!IsPostBack){}

Comment: Add if(!isPostback) where you can retrieve the values form ViewState...otherwise your label will reset to it's default state as it is NOT the same label, but always a newly created one.

Comment: Can you give us a simple code that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Therein lies your issue. When your page is posting back the label is getting assigned the value:

```
 lblMsg.Text = "Must be an Admin in delete.";
```

But Page_Load gets called again. So your Page_Load should look like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if(!IsPostBack) {
     //Populate my page
  }
}
```

This will hold true for almost every page you write in ASP.NET

Comment: Mac, I commented the code out in my page load: // lblMsg.Text = "Sample Text goes here."; Shouldn't it show up as there is no overwritting

Comment: Would you be able to post the rest of your "code behind" code? Either 1: something else is setting the value or 2: You are in the "Administrator" group you are checking against.